# CKEditor5: support for content not to be processed through the conversion pipeline

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

We are looking to refactor our Email editor to CKEditor5 from CKEditor4. Now our email content can come from anywhere, for example, Outlook, Gmail, etc, each having its own way of representing its HTML data. What we want is to show these HTML content as is, without the HTML tags going through the conversions to the [CKEditor5 custom model](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#model).

So far, I have got suggestions to just create a custom converter but it's extremely tedious to go through all email clients and how each email client generates HTML. Ideally, we would like to wrap our email content with a `<div class='transparent'></div>` and CK5 should understand not to put any underlying HTML through the conversion pipeline.

Is there any plugin that is readily available for this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

CKE5 added a feature named [General Experimental Support(GHS)](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/general-html-support.html)(Experimental) which adds behavior to add any HTML tag not supported by the CKE5 custom schema model.